# How to make authorization with multiple screens in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new at FLutter and I want to try to make authorization but I don't know how to do it properly.

I have multiple screens with inputs

First screen: Choose country in textFormField => Second screen: type name, email in textFormFields => Third screen: type and confirm password in textFormFields

And when I press sign up button, I should send country, name, email and password to a server.

But where to store values of previous screens. Should I just transfer all data from one screen to another using navigator, or there is a better solution?

I know in React exists redux or mobX(state manager) but do we have something similar in flutter?

Comment: You can do either ways: 1. Passing data of each screen/page to the next page and so on. 2. By making different widgets for each screen and show single widget step by step ( by showing widget 1 first, then hide the first one and show the 2nd widget and so on. ) in a single screen/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just transfer all data from one screen to another using
> navigator

No, this will work but, when your project grows up, it will be a mess.

> I know in React exists redux or mobX(state manager) but do we have
> something similar in flutter?

Yes, Flutter have redux and mobX lib too, you can take a look on [flutter_redux](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux), [mobx](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx), and some other famous state management:
[provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). If you are a new one, I think provider will be easier to learn, bloc is more boilerplate code but it'll be good with big projects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send all data from one screen,
but it depends on which state management method you will use, you can save the data in the controller if you decide to use (provider, Getx) or in a cubit, if you choose to use(Cubit state management )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).